# Create an object with an array as a parameter

Tags: c++, object

Here's what I've got, the error is showing in the fourth to last line with the '='. I've tried to construct that line in several different ways, but they all give me errors. I think it is probably in the constructor itself. I have tried a bit of the stuff with '*' and '&' but I don't know how those work and nothing I tried seemed to work.

````
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class AudioCD{
  public:
  string cdTitle;
  string artists[4];
  int releaseYear;
  string genre;
  float condition;

  AudioCD(){
    cdTitle = "";
    for(int i = 0; i<4; i++){
    artists[i] = "";
    }
    releaseYear = 1980;
    genre = "";
    condition = 0.0;
  }

  AudioCD(string newCDTitle, string newArtists[4], int newReleaseYear, string newGenre, float newCondition){
    cdTitle = newCDTitle;
    for(int i; i < 4; i++){
      artists[i] = newArtists[i];
    }
    if(newReleaseYear < 1980){
      releaseYear = 1980;
    }
    else{
      releaseYear = newReleaseYear;
    }
    genre = newGenre;
    if(newCondition > 5.0 || newCondition < 0.0){
      condition = 0.0;
    }
    else{
      condition = newCondition;
    }
  }

  void getCDInfo(int cdNum){
    cout << cdNum << ". " << cdTitle << ", " << releaseYear << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
      if(artists[i].compare("")!=0){
        cout << "Artist (#" << i << "): " << artists[i] << endl;
      }
    }
    cout << "Genre: " << genre << endl;
    cout << "Condition: " << condition << endl;
  }
};

int main() {
  int arraySize;
  string title;
  string artists[4];
  int releaseYear;
  string genre;
  float condition;

  cout << "[Rate Audio CD Collection]" << endl;
  cout << "How many CDs do you have lying around your car? ";
  cin >> arraySize;
  AudioCD cdArray[arraySize];
  for(int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++){
    cout << "Enter Title: ";
    cin >> title;
    cout << "Enter Artists (type -1 when finished)" << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
      string tempArtist;
      cin >> tempArtist;
      if(tempArtist.compare("-1")!=0){
        artists[i]=tempArtist;
      }
      else{
        break;
      }
    }
    cout << "Enter Genre: ";
    cin >> genre;
    cout << "Enter Release Year: ";
    cin >> releaseYear;
    cout << "Enter Condition: ";
    cin >> condition;

    cdArray[i] = new AudioCD(title, artists, releaseYear, genre, condition);
  }
  cdArray[1].getCDInfo(1);
}```
````

Comment: In the future, please post the full error message from your compiler since it contains a lot of useful info that makes it easier to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is probably giving you a useful error message that says something like `cannot convert from 'AudioCD *' to 'AudioCD'`.  The issue is that when you use the `new` keyword, you are actually allocating new memory for your object and you are getting a pointer to the object.  The pointer has type `AudioCD *`.  But there is no need to allocate memory: you already allocated enough memory when you defined your `cdArray` array above.  Each element in the array is an actual AudioCD object, not just a pointer to one.

Try removing `new` from that line, so it becomes:

```
cdArray[i] = AudioCD(title, artists, releaseYear, genre, condition);
```

Then the types on the left and right side of the assignment will match.

Comment: `cdArray[i] = {title, artists, releaseYear, genre, condition};` is also possible; avoiding a bit of repetition